# Which file path emulates Console for e.g. Out-File?

Tags: powershell, io-redirection

I have a function that writes to a file. **Note: I can't change this function - it's provided to me by an external module.**

```
function myFunc($file) {
    "something myFunc says" | Out-File $file -Append
}
```

How can I call this function so it outputs to console, like the DOS `con` pseudo-file? Calling `myFunc("con")` yields error `Out-File : The handle is invalid.`

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change the module to ouput the text then get the contents of $file and write it to the console as follow:

```
$text = Get-Content $file
Write-Host $text
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a reasonable workaround. I was hoping for something that would direct the file directly to console, again like DOS' `con`.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand your question exactly.
What I understood is that you wanna output text to a txt file for example but with cmd.exe for example ?

open a cmd window and try the following

```
echo some text > %userprofile%\Desktop\file.txt
```

this will output your text in a text file

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use your function and append text to the text file use the following:

```
function myFunc($file) {
    Add-Content -Path $file -Value "something myFunc says"
}
```

Comment: The point is that I need to use this (example) function as-is, since it's provided to me externally. I wrote in the question "a function I can't change" - I edited the question to emphasize that.